# Is there a way to convert zip+4 codes to latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I have the zip+4 codes, and I want to extract their longitude and latitude codes.

I tried using pgeocode but this package does not have any zip+4 data in it. What package can I use? pgeocode only has these columns: country_code, postal_code, place_name, state_name, state_code, county_name, county_code, community_name, community_code, latitude, longitude.

I did this -

```
import pgeocode 
nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('us') 
nomi.query_postal_code("360672303")
```

and got this -

```
postal_code 360672303 
country_code NaN 
place_name NaN 
state_name NaN 
state_code NaN 
county_name NaN 
county_code NaN 
community_name NaN 
community_code NaN 
latitude NaN 
longitude NaN 
accuracy NaN
```

But the co-ordinates for 36067-2303 are lon:-86.477408, lat:32.470205.

Comment: Here's [a discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233982/us-zip-codes-4-by-state-or-county-shapefile-or-table-dbf) about mapping zip+4 on gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank u for the link! I already have the zip+4 data. What I am looking for code help to attain its corresponding lat and long coordinates

Comment: have you tried: `math.asinh(lat) + math.tan(math.sqrt(~math.pow(lon, int(math.trunc(2e-3))) ** -217.3)) if  0.5 ** ~3 > lon > -218 else math.acos(lon ** -12)` ?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The last four digits (`'xxxxx-2303'`) of a `postal_code` represents the specific delivery routes within delivery areas, and although the extra detail makes it more precise it isn't the expected input for `query_postal_code` so try inputting just `'36067'`:

```
nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('us')
a = nomi.query_postal_code('36067')
print(a['latitude'], a['longitude'])
```

Outputs:

```
32.4715 -86.4831
```

`print(a)`:

```
postal_code            36067
country_code              US
place_name        Prattville
state_name           Alabama
state_code                AL
county_name          Autauga
county_code              1.0
community_name           NaN
community_code           NaN
latitude             32.4715
longitude           -86.4831
accuracy                 4.0
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: yes, but I need to be able to convert zip+4 codes to lat and long coordinates, not zip codes to lat long coordinates.

Comment: query_postal_code() does not support zip+4 (https://readthedocs.org/projects/pgeocode/downloads/pdf/latest/), only 5 digit postal codes. The zip code is the 5 digit postal code, the additional 4 digits are just extra info that isn't needed to specify a location.

Comment: Yes, i know that. i added that to my description and asked if there are any other packages with zip+4 data that i could use?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any packages that will accept zip+4, but if I do I'll update my answer.